# Popup Login Joomla Rockettheme

Tags: php, joomla

I know this is not a correct question but I dont know where to go, rocket forums wont accept guests :|
I've followed the tutorial on how to add a popup login and everything works except when I click the login button, then nothing happens, it only displays a "#" on the URL, the login.php contains this syntax code: href="#"
I'm probably missing something but I dont know what?

code login.php

```
    <?php
defined('JPATH_BASE') or die();
gantry_import('core.gantryfeature');
class GantryFeatureLogin extends GantryFeature {
    var $_feature_name = 'login';
    function render($position="") {
        ob_start();
        $user =& JFactory::getUser();
        ?>
        <div class="rt-block">
            <div class="rt-popupmodule-button">
            <?php if ($user->guest) : ?>
                <a href="#" class="buttontext button" rel="rokbox[355 385][module=rt-popuplogin]">
                    <span class="desc"><?php echo $this->get('text'); ?></span>
                </a>
            <?php else : ?>
                <a href="#" class="buttontext button" rel="rokbox[355 385][module=rt-popuplogin]">
                    <span class="desc"><?php echo $this->get('logouttext'); ?> <?php echo JText::sprintf($user->get('username')); ?></span>
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}

<?php
```

Documentation: http://gantry-framework.org/documentation/joomla/tutorials/creating_popup_login.md

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Rockettheme Rokbox plugin first.

http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-downloads/free/1005-rokbox

If already installed, make sure it is published.

Comment: The problem was I had turned off backwards compatibility feature, after that it works, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but the problem is still relevant because many of the RocketTheme templates includes a login-button with the old syntax. Here's the same code as above, but with the new RokBox 2 syntax for the link (`<a href="#" class="readon buttontext" rel="rokbox[385 160][module=rt-popuplogin]">`

The RokBox compatibility setting might give your site a performance hit.

```
<?php
defined('JPATH_BASE') or die();
gantry_import('core.gantryfeature');
class GantryFeatureLogin extends GantryFeature {
    var $_feature_name = 'login';
    function render($position="") {
        ob_start();
        $user =& JFactory::getUser();
        ?>
        <div class="rt-block">
            <div class="rt-popupmodule-button">
            <?php if ($user->guest) : ?>
                <a href="#" class="buttontext button" data-rokbox data-rokbox-element="#rt-popuplogin" data-rokbox-size="385 160">
                    <span class="desc"><?php echo $this->get('text'); ?></span>
                </a>
            <?php else : ?>
                <a href="#" class="buttontext button" data-rokbox data-rokbox-element="#rt-popuplogin" data-rokbox-size="385 160">
                    <span class="desc"><?php echo $this->get('logouttext'); ?> <?php echo JText::sprintf($user->get('username')); ?></span>
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```